# Converse of Slutsky's theorem (or counterexample)?

Tags: probability-theory

**Question**

Suppose $X_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} X$ and $Z_n \overset{p}{\nrightarrow} 0$. Does it follow that $X_n + Z_n \overset{d}{\nrightarrow} X$.

If not, what's a counterexample?

**Thoughts**

This would be a sort of converse to Slutsky's theorem. If $Z_n \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} 0$, then Slutsky's theorem would tell us that $X_n + Z_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} X$.

I imagine this isn't true, since it would probably just be included in standard formulations of Slutsky's theorem if it were. But it would be nice to have a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is not almost surely constant, and let $Y$ be independent of $X$ but with the same distribution. Set $X_n=X$ and $Z_n=Y-X$.

Then $X_n\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}X$, $Z_n\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}Y-X\neq0$ but $X_n+Z_n\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}X$.